# get Day of week PHP 5 Calendar Functions

Tags: php

I want to make a schedule based on calendar.
Using PHP5 calendar function i discover the strange behavior:
code below return the same value for both variables.

```
<?php

$day=gregoriantojd(31,10,2016);
echo jddayofweek($day, 1) ."<hr>";

$day2=gregoriantojd(1,11,2016);
echo jddayofweek($day2, 1);

?>
```

Comment: just out of curiosity: why do you even need julian dates for a schedule? doesn't the whole world use gregorian?

Comment: I'm just learning. Found this solution on w3school, Thank you for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php):

```
int gregoriantojd ( int $month , int $day , int $year )
```

gregoriantojd takes the month first and the day second. so the input 31,10,2016 is plain wrong, results in a return value of 0, which coincidentally is the same weekday as the 11th january 2016.

try this:

```
<?php

$day=gregoriantojd(10,31,2016);
echo jddayofweek($day, 1) ."<hr>";

$day2=gregoriantojd(11,1,2016);
echo jddayofweek($day2, 1);
```

and you will get monday and tuesday respectively.